# Set representation of Ball in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

While studying optimization, I came across the following problem:

**Problem: (exactly as written in Boyd's convex optimization book)**

We consider the problem of finding the largest Euclidean ball that lies in a polyhedron described by linear inequalities,
$$
\mathcal{P}=\left\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{n} \mid a_{i}^{T} x \leq b_{i}, i=1, \ldots, m\right\}
$$
(The center of the optimal ball is called the Chebyshev center of the polyhedron; it is the point deepest inside the polyhedron, i.e., farthest from the boundary; see $\S 8.5 .1 .$ ) We represent the ball as
$$
\mathcal{B}=\left\{x_{c}+u \mid\|u\|_{2} \leq r\right\}
$$
The variables in the problem are the center $x_{c} \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$ and the radius $r$; we wish to maximize $r$ subject to the constraint $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}$.

**What is the issue?**

I cannot figure out why we can represent the ball as:
$$
\mathcal{B}=\left\{x_{c}+u \mid\|u\|_{2} \leq r\right\}
$$

The description I have always used is as follows:

$$
B_{2}\left(x_{c}, r\right)=\left\{x \mid\left\|x-x_{c}\right\|_{2} \leq r\right\}=\left\{x \mid\left(x-x_{c}\right)^{T}\left(x-x_{c}\right) \leq r^{2}\right\}
$$

In fact, Boyd even mentions that the ball can be written as:
$$
B_{1}\left(x_{c}, r\right)=\left\{x_{c}+r u \mid\|u\|_{2} \leq 1\right\}
$$

So **what I am trying to achieve** is a proof which clearly states that $$B_{1} = B_{2}$$

**Attempt:**

Let's prove that $B_{1} \subseteq B_{2}$. Let $p \in B_{1}\left(x_{c}, r\right)$. Then
$$
p-x_{c}=r u \Rightarrow\left\|p-x_{c}\right\|=\|r u\|=|r| \cdot\|u\| \leqslant r \cdot 1
$$

which implies that $p \in B_{2}\left(x_{c}, r\right)$.

Now we must prove that $B_{2} \subset B_{1}$. **I have no idea.** I got stuck and the only thing I was able to do was picking $p \in B_{2}\left(x_{c}, r\right)$ and writing what it was supposed to satisfy, but it did not go further than that.

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: Here's a hint, because this exercise is not too tricky: if we pick some $x \in B_2$, and wish to write $x = x_c + ru$, then try solving for $u$. Can you show that this $u$ satisfies $\|u\|_2 \le 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use essentially the same argument in reverse.

Let $p\in B_2$. $\|p-x_c\|\le r\implies\|p-x_c\|=r\cdot\theta,\,\theta\in[0,1]$. Since $r$ is positive, $r=|r|$. Now $\|p-x_c\|=|r|\cdot\|u\|,\,\|u\|=\theta\in[0,1]\implies\|p-x_c\|=\|ru\|$ and $p-x_c=ru,\,p=ru+x_c\in B_1$.

Note that two vectors may have the same magnitude but still be different, but importantly all possible equivalent $p$ such that $\|p-x_c\|=\|ru\|$, for some $u$, are also contained in either ball.

Therefore $p\in B_2\implies p\in B_1,p\in B_1\implies p\in B_2\therefore B_1(r,x_c)=B_2(r,x_c)$.

Comment: Super duper nice! Do you think my proof regarding $B_{1} \subset B_{2}$ is correct?

Comment: I think it is correct, but I must say that you should write $\subseteq$, not $\subset$, because the latter usually means a proper subset, whereas you proved only $\subseteq$ (which in fact is correct since the equality case is true). If you don’t know, you do this in MathJax like this: `\subseteq` for $\subseteq$ and `\subsetneq` for $\subsetneq$ when you really want to emphasise that equality isn’t possible @Lucas